# How to answer smart phone from multiple bluetooth headsets

Tags: bluetooth

I use a smartphone for my business, not a land line.  There are 2 of us who answer the phone, depending on who is busy at the time.

I am trying to find a solution which allows either of us to pick up the phone call, just as if the cell phone was the land line base and it can be picked up from any wireless extension phone (but using blutooth headsets/ear pieces)

Currently it automatically send the call to the first Bluetooth attached so the other person does not have an option to pick up the phone call.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple headsets ringing at the same time by pairing multiple Bluetooth headsets to a single iPhone.

Various solutions exists for having multiple headphones connected to the iPhone at the same time. For example in earlier days you had headphone-jack splitters, then Bluetooth splitters - and now Apple has their own built-in support for multiple listeners.

However that is all it is - multiple listeners. Even with one of the external Bluetooth splitters available for the iPhone, you can only listen to audio - it doesn't work with the microphone.

In order to achieve the effect you want, you'll need to have two cellphones, and have your provider set it up so that both ring when a call comes in. This can be done via traditional cell phone technology, or it can be a Voice over IP solution - in that case you could also use an iPod Touch, iPad or other device.